# Android Auto notification not showing

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-auto

I'm attempting to show a notification through Android Auto. The notification *does* show on my phone. However, it is *not* showing on Android Auto emulator. This is a media application.

automotvie_app_desc.xml:

```
<automotiveApp>
    <uses name="media"/>
</automotiveApp>
```

This code is in my `MediaBrowserService` class:

```
private Notification postNotification(AutoNotificationHelper.Type type) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Post Notification");
    Notification notification = AutoNotificationHelper.createMenuErrorNotification(
            getApplicationContext(), type, mSession);

    if (notification != null) {
        mNotificationManager.notify(TAG, NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
    return notification;
}
```

Here is where the notification is created:

```
static Notification createMenuErrorNotification(Context context, Type type,
                                                MediaSessionCompat mediaSession) {

    MediaControllerCompat controller = mediaSession.getController();
    MediaMetadataCompat mMetadata = controller.getMetadata();
    PlaybackStateCompat mPlaybackState = controller.getPlaybackState();

    if (mMetadata == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MetaData is null");
    }

    if (mPlaybackState == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Playback state is null");
    }

    if (type.equals(Type.MENU_ERROR)) {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.error);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context.getApplicationContext());
        notificationBuilder.extend(new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.CarExtender())
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.error)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.message))
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }

    return null;
}
```

What am I missing to get this to show on the auto display and not on the phone?

Answer (score 2):

**NotificationCompat.CarExtender** seems to be an option only for app declare as "notification" (message read and response feature for a messaging app for example).

```
<automotiveApp>
    <uses name="notification"/>
</automotiveApp>
```

Display notification on home in "Auto" context with a "media" automotiveApp seems not allowed in actual api version.

For an error message associated to a media playing app (like it seems to be in your case) you can use error state which will be interpreted and displayed directly by Auto system.

```
private void showErrorMessage(final int errorCode, final String errorMessage) {
    final PlaybackStateCompat.Builder playbackStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
    playbackStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_ERROR, -1L, 1.0F);
    playbackStateBuilder.setErrorMessage(errorCode, errorMessage);
    mSession.setPlaybackState(playbackStateBuilder.build());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to show the notification,

```
 private void showPushNotification(String title, String message, Intent tapIntent, int notificationID) {
        android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.swiftee_white_logo_notification);
        //Intent tapIntent = new Intent(this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
        //tapIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        //tapIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //tapIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.PUSH_MESSAGE, true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, tapIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(message);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, builder.build());
    }
```

Comment: This is still only showing the notification on the phone and not on the auto head unit.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow step by step from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MessagingService)

This sample demonstrate full demo

**EDIT**

For Media Notification you can use [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-music-player/index.html#0) . Here step by step explained about media app and notification for auto

Comment: The demo app is a notification application. Can an application be both notification and media?

Comment: Also,this can be helpful https://developer.android.com/training/auto/audio/index.html